# Resolve combine future outside of future's closure

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm using [Future](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future) to create a publisher that returns a single value from outside of the future creation closure. For this, I store the [promise](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future/promise) property locally:

```
return Future<Something, Never> { promise in
   self.somePromise = promise
}.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Then after some work is finished I resolve the promise:

```
self.somePromise(.success(data))
```

I've searched the documentation and haven't found any references, is this a correct usage or is there a better way to do it?

To put it more into context, my idea is to have some kind of "broker" class, that returns promises and that at some time in the future will publish a result:

```
class FruitBroker {
    
    // MARK: - Private Properties
    private var applePromise: Future<[Apple], Never>.Promise!
    private var orangePromise: Future<[Orange], Never>.Promise!
    
    // MARK: - Methods
    func getApples() -> AnyPublisher<[Apple], Never> {
        return Future<[Apple], Never> { promise in
           self.applePromise = promise
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getBananas() -> AnyPublisher<[Orange], Never> {
        return Future<[Orange], Never> { promise in
           self.orangePromise = promise
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private Methods
    private func onHarvestFinished() {
        applePromise(.success(apples))
        orangePromise(.success(oranges))
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be challenging to suggest a different or better way without having any context about what is getting done in the interim or how it is getting done. For example, I’d probably prefer to pass a reference to the promise rather than storing it, but it is impossible to say if that would work for you.

Comment: A word of caution with your question if I may? You asked this one hour ago - and basically that makes it two hours before Apple (who pretty much owns Combine) begins WWDC 2021. Maybe wait a day to see what (much needed) improvements they make?

Comment: @jnpdx I've added a little more context although I'm not sure it will be of much help

Comment: This looks to me like you should be using something like `PassthroughSubject` to just `send()` a value instead of trying to store `Future`s

Comment: But a `Future` ensures you can only resolve/cancel it once. `PassthroughSubject` doesn't.

Comment: Indeed @Era, at the time of the question I was trying to implement the same behaviour of an RxSwift Single trait.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a situation where you should just use `PassthroughSubject` or `CurrentValueSubject`:

```
class FruitBroker {
    
    var applePublisher = PassthroughSubject<[Apple],Never>()
    var orangePublisher = PassthroughSubject<[Orange],Never>()
    
    private func onHarvestFinished(apples: [Apple], oranges: [Orange]) {
        applePublisher.send(apples)
        orangePublisher.send(oranges)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question or was it helpful at all?

Answer (score 0):

> is this a correct usage

No. What you're doing is not Combine. Combine is publisher -> operators -> subscriber, where this path constitutes a pipeline. You have no pipeline. You're just storing a method and later calling it; you don't need a Combine Future to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me:

```swift
public class Promise<V, E: Error> {
  private let currentSubject: CurrentValueSubject<V?, E>

  public init() {
    currentSubject = .init(nil)
  }

  public func resolve(_ value: V) {
    currentSubject.send(value)
  }

  public func reject(error: E) {
    currentSubject.send(completion: .failure(error))
  }

  public var publisher: AnyPublisher<V, E> {
    currentSubject.compactMap { $0 }
      .first()
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```